# Does top read some system files?

Tags: linux, top, virtual-memory

If I am correct, the output of `free` comes from reading `/proc/meminfo`.

In the output of `top`,

- is the summary of memory part not specific to a process also coming from `/proc/meminfo`?
- which system files does the memory information for each process come from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `strace` to figure out what files a program is using. For example:

```
strace -f -o top.log -e trace=file top
```

Then just press `q` to quit `top`. A file `top.log` has been created that shows which files `top` did access while it was running.

Essentially, it seems to be `/proc/<pid>/{stat,statm}` for the PIDs of all running processes, and the following files (`/proc/` and all libraries removed):

```
host ~ # cat top.log | sed 's/.*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' | grep -vE '(/proc/|/lib/)' | sort | uniq
9375  +++ exited with 0 +++
/dev/null
/etc/ld.so.cache
/etc/ld.so.nohwcap
/etc/ld.so.preload
/etc/localtime
/etc/nsswitch.conf
/etc/passwd
/etc/terminfo
/etc/terminfo/s/screen
/etc/toprc
/lib
/proc
/sys/devices/system/cpu/online
top
/usr/lib
/usr/share/locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/procps-ng.mo
/usr/share/locale/de_DE.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/procps-ng.mo
/usr/share/locale/de_DE.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/procps-ng.mo
/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/procps-ng.mo
/usr/share/locale/de.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/procps-ng.mo
/usr/share/locale/de.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/procps-ng.mo
/usr/share/locale/locale.alias
/usr/share/terminfo
/var/run/utmp
/var/run/utmpx
```